# Combining two Enumeratees

Tags: haskell, loops

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `enumerator` library and ran into a situation where I want to build a new Enumeratee in terms of two existing Enumeratees. Let's say I have the enumeratees:

```
e1 :: Enumeratee x y m b
e2 :: Enumeratee y z m b
```

I feel that I should be able to combine them into one enumeratee

```
e3 :: Enumeratee x z m b
```

but I couldn't find an existing function to do this in the package. I tried to write such a function myself, but my understanding of iteratees is still so limited that I couldn't figure out a way to get all the complex types to match.

Did I just miss some basic combinator, or are Enumeratees even supposed to be composable with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory they are composable, but the types are a bit tricky.  The difficulty is that the final parameter `b` of the first enumeratee isn't actually `b`; it's another iteratee!.  Here's the type of the `><>` operator from [iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee), which composes enumeratees:

```
Prelude Data.Iteratee> :t (><>)
(><>)
  :: (Monad m, Nullable s1) =>
     (forall x. Enumeratee s1 s2 m x)
     -> Enumeratee s2 s3 m a -> Enumeratee s1 s3 m a
```

Note the extra `forall` in the first enumeratee; this indicates that a Rank-2 type is at work.  If the `enumerator` author wants to maintain H98 compatibility (I believe this was one of the original goals), this approach is unavailable.

It is possible to write this type signature in a form which doesn't require Rank-2 types, but it's either longer, not clear from the type that it's actually two enumeratee's that are being composed, or both.  For example, this is ghc's inferred type for `(><>)`:

```
Prelude Data.Iteratee> :t (><>>)
(><>>)
  :: (Monad m, Nullable s) =>
     (b -> Iteratee s m (Iteratee s' m a1))
     -> (a -> b) -> a -> Iteratee s m a1
```

Although these types are for `iteratee` combinators, hopefully it's enough information you'll be able to apply them to `enumerator`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran with this problem a while ago, you need to have an Iteratee first (or an Enumerator) in order to make the composition of Enumeratees.

You can either start by doing this:

```
module Main where
import Data.Enumerator
import qualified Data.Enumerator.List as EL

main :: IO ()
main = run_ (enum $$ EL.consume) >>= print
  where
    enum  = (enumList 5 [1..] $= EL.isolate 100) $= EL.filter pairs
    pairs = (==0) . (`mod` 2)
```

The previous code composes a list of enumeratees together to create a new enumerator, and then it is applied to the consume Iteratee.

The ($=) serves to compose **an Enumerator and an Enumeratee to create a new enumerator**, while the (=$) can be used to compose **an Iteratee with an Enumeratee to create a new Iteratee**. I recommend the latter given that types won't bust your balls when composing a list of Enumeratees using (=$):

```
module Main where
import Data.Enumerator
import qualified Data.Enumerator.List as EL

main :: IO ()
main = run_ (enumList 5 [1..] $$ it) >>= print
  where 
    it = foldr (=$)
               EL.consume
               [ EL.isolate 100
               , EL.filter ((==0) . (`mod` 2))
               ]
```

If you would try to implement the same function above by creating an Enumerator instead of an Iteratee, you will get an infinite recursive type error when using `foldl' ($=) (enumList 5 [1..]) [list-of-enumeratees]`.

Hope this helps.